# EMV Reading PAN Code

Tags: apdu, emv

I need to read the PAN Code of every possible card through chip.
In my job I have to use only C and I haven't routines that can help me in this boring task.
So that's the steps APDU that I use:

1) SELECT 1PAY.SYS.DDF01

```
00 A4 0400 0E 315041592E5359532E4444463031
```

and then `00 C0 0000 22 315041592E5359532E4444463031` from the response to read all datas.
Complete Response:

`6f 20 e 84 31 50 41 59 2e 53 59 53 2e 44 44 46 30 31 a5 e 88 1 1 5f 2d 69 8 74 65 6e 66 72 65 73 90`

2) READ RECORD to get the specific AID

```
00 B2 010C 00
```

Complete Response:

```
70 17 61 15 4f 7 a0 0 0 0 4 30 60 50 7 4d 41 53 54 52 45 4f 87 1 1 90
```

3) SELECT AID (in my case the AID is A0000000043060 from the previous response)

```
00 A4 0400 07 A0000000043060
```

Also in this case, I have response: 61 36, so I re-call the command with:

```
00 C0 0000 36 A0000000043060
```

Complete Response:

```
6f 0 41 45 53 52 4f 54 87 1 1 34 84 a0 7 0 0 4 30 60 a5 29 50 7 4d 5f 2d 8 69 74 65 6e 72 66 65 73 bf c f 9f 4d 2 b a 9f 6e 3 7 80 0 0 30 30 0 90
```

Now every command that I use, will get wrong message.
I don't understand if I have to use READ DATA, READ RECORD, GET PROCESSING OPTIONS or something else.
Can you give me a tip on what I have to do now?

I need to get the 16 char code of the card, the one that is normally printed clearly on the card.

Thanks to everyone

Comment: can you tell why you need the pan/track data alone ?

Comment: @Valerio colonnese Are you talking about the 16 digit numeric  code printed on each card..?? If yes then it is possible to retrieve but what is the use case for you?. I am asking because this is one of the sensitive information stored in card.

Comment: @Gaurav_Orai I have to tokenize it for a program of loyalty card.

Comment: I want to detail my answer: I need only the PAN code because  I have to map it with a custom card for a loyalty service. I have to call my API with that code, I'm not interested to do payment with that, so I don't need expyration date, PIN, or anything of banking services.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The 8 Byte (16 Digit) code printed on Smart Card (Payment Chip Card) is retrievable. This information is the  part of "Track 2 Equivalent Data" personalized in the records in Tag 57.

You can slice the initial 8 Bytes of this "Track 2 Equivalent Data" to get your code.

Now How to Get "Track 2 Equivalent Data":

1. SELECT Payment Application (excluding the PSE/PPSE process here, since you are able to do it)
2. Send GPO command. Normally 80 A8 00 00 02 83 00 is the APDU for GPO if no PDOL data is required in GPO command APDU. (If 9F38 tag is not present in the response of SELCT command then Simply send this APDU, otherwise PDOL must be created). See EMV 4.3 Book 3 Section 6.5.8 for more details about GPO response.
3. You will get AFL in the response of GPO and Read all the available records from application as per AFL. Normally track 2 data could be found within 2 or 3 initial records.

   To understand the coding of AFL you can refer Section 10.2 EMV 4.3 Book 3.

   To understand the READ RECORD APDU construction refer EMV 4.3 Book 1 Section 11.2.
4. One of record must contain Tag 57 and you can fetch the value.

Comment: There is also a tag 5A - Application Primary Account Number (PAN) in  EMV card, can also read this tag from AFL to get only 16 digit PAN Number.

Comment: @Arjun yes it could be another solution.

Comment: @Gaurav_Orai Thanks for the answer.
So I've tried to send the GPO as described in your answer.
I'd got a 12 chars AFL response with values 10 02 04 01 18 01 01 00 20 01 01 00
So, EMV 4.3 Book 3, I have 3 files that I have to read.

I have to send 3 READ record command with params in the AFL
So, for example, to build those command I used:
02 B2 02 04 01 
for the first quartet, where 02 is 10 (first byte) >> 3, B2 is  READ RECORD, and the other 3 bytes from the previous response.
But I have always response 6E 00, Class not supported.

Comment: Considering 10 02 04 01 18 01 01 00 20 01 01 00 as AFL which is returned in response of GPO.
Now dividing this into the chunks of 4-4 Bytes.
1. 10 02 04 01 - SFI 2 Record 2 to 4
2. 18 01 01 00 - SFI 3 Record 1 only
3. 20 01 01 00 - SFI 4 Record 1 only

So Now the Read record command to Read all the records would be like:

00 B2 02 14 00 to Read the 2nd Record of SFI 2
00 B2 03 14 00 to Read the 2nd Record of SFI 2
00 B2 04 14 00 to Read the 2nd Record of SFI 2
00 B2 01 1C 00 to Read the only available 1st Record of SFI 3
00 B2 01 24 00 to Read the only available 1st Record of SFI 3

Comment: try this and let me know

Comment: Thanks @Gaurav_Orai
It worked fine!!! Thanks also to Arjun for the answer, the tag 5A it's correct!